# How to redirect to a login virtual page?

Tags: url-rewriting, page-template, rewrite-rules

I'm writing my first WordPress theme from scratch. I need to redirect not logged in users to a virtual login page, when I do `wp_safe_redirect( get_site_url() . '/login' )` I would show a virtual page based on a template.

I wrote:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'include_theme_template');
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'virtual_pages_rewrite_rules');
```

and the callbacks:

```
public function include_theme_template() {
    $page_id = intval( get_query_var( 'page_id' ) );
    if ( $page_id = 255) {
        include get_template_directory() . '/templates/template-login.php';
        die;
    }
}

public function virtual_pages_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge(
        ['login/' => 'index.php?page_id=255'],
        $wp_rewrite->rules
    );
}
```

What's wrong?
How must I write the rewrite rules?

Comment: Why don't you just create a page called "Login" (and with the slug `login`), and assign the login template to that page? That way, there's no need for those hooks.

Comment: For my specific purpose I can't create new "physical" pages in WordPress backend. There must be one physical page only and then I have to create one or more virtual pages when/if I need it...

Comment: In that case, then you can simply use the [`parse_request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/) hook to load the template as well as handling the virtual path (`/login`).

Comment: You say you can't create a physical page, but your code is hard-coded to depend on a specific page ID. Surely that's no better? Could you elaborate on the circumstances behind your limitations?

Comment: Thank you for your replies... Due to change in my mind, I decided to create automatically physical pages when switched to my theme in admin pages.